# How does heat energy travel in space?

Tags: thermodynamics, radiation, thermal-radiation

How does the heat energy from the Sun reach us on the Earth? Since the kinetic energy of an atom is the amount of heat energy and there is no matter in space, how does heat from the Sun reach us?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three ways by which heat can be transferred:

1.Conduction

2.Convection

3.Radiation

The first two ways require a medium while the last one doesn't. The energy from the sun reaches our earth through radiation i.e in the form of electromagnetic radiation(in simple words light). The photons which constitute light has momentum and energy. When these photons collide with particles the particles acquire energy and thus their speed(kinetic energy) increases.

This causes the thermal energy of the particles to increase and not the heat energy. Heat is a term used for energy in transfer.

Comment: And the solar wind would be transferring energy (heat) via convection.

Comment: " When these photons collide with particles they acquire energy and thus their speed(kinetic energy) increases." is very misleading. Photons from the sun lose energy by scatterings as the interstellar space has very low kinetic energy dust and particles. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering

Comment: I added the word "particles" to make the meaning clear